# SQL Server 2008: Insert variable into DML statements using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1] 
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [My_Database].[My_Schema].[My_Table]
(...lists columns...)
SELECT ...  lots of columns from joined query... 

END
```

Instead of hardcoding "[My_Database].[My_Schema]", I now want to select it as a variable from a predefined table like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test1] 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @myDB = [My_DB] FROM [my_custom_table]

--INSERT INTO [My_Database].[My_Schema].[My_Table]

INSERT INTO @myDB.[My_Table]
(...lists columns...)
SELECT ...  lots of columns from joined query... 

END
```

It does not work if I use it like above. I need to use:
EXEC sp_executesql (entire_sql_statement_in_quotes)

My problem is that I have a lot of these procedures to change to using a variable instead of being hardcoded. It will take forever to convert each statement to a long string.

Is there some other way to do it? What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea, you could drop and recreate a synonym using dynamic SQL at the beginning of each procedure, then you can leave each Insert statement as Insert Into MySynonym

```
DROP SYNONYM MySynonym -- Must create it first before running this bit!

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'CREATE SYNONYM MySynonym
FOR ' + @myDB + '.test1'
EXEC sp_Executesql @sql

INSERT INTO MySynonym 
SELECT ...
```

This would give you a peice  of code you could copy paste into each SP.  If the table you are inserting into is different for each SP, you could declare that too and build it into your CREATE SYNONYM statement

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE SYNONYM MySynonym
FOR ' + @myDB + '.' + @MyTable
```

to Truncate each table first you would need to use DynamicSQL also, as you cannot delete on a synonym

```
SET @SQL = 'Truncate Table ' + @MyTable
EXEC sp_Executesql @sql
```

Comment: Should I not use sp_Executesql(@sql)?

Comment: yes indeed, I'd left that out, I have updated my answer

Comment: EXEC sp_Executesql '@sql'

Comment: I forgot to mention I want to truncate each table first, apologies. So I get the error: Could not truncate object 'Syn_Generic_BI' because it is not a table. Could I use delete on a synonym?

Comment: you could still use generic dynamicSQL to truncate the table, this would still give you a single block of sql to copy paste into each SP.  I have updated my answer